# angularjs 1.3.16 routing with html5mode, url is updating but content not updating

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes, ngroute, html5mode

We are using AngularJS version 1.3.16 and nodeJS as backend, ng-route for angular routing. Working code consists of #! as URL separator for node and angular.

Example URLs:
/store/1234/#!/department/produce
/store/1234/#!/department/produce/category/fruits

NodeJS Routing code:

```
    app.get('/store/:storeid', ctrl.storeView);
```

Angular routing code:

```
      $routeProvider.when('/department/:deptIndex', {
    controller: 'CartController',
    resolve: {
        // I will cause a 1 second delay
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}).when('/department/:deptIndex/category/:catIndex', {
    controller: 'CartController',
    resolve: {
        // I will cause a 1 second delay
        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
```

To make the URLs SEO friendly and crawlable we have to remove the hashbang from URL.
So, the issue arises when we are trying to enable the html5 mode. The angular routing is not working after the mode is enabled.

Comment: Can you give more details on what "not working" means? Is an error being thrown? Is the screen blank? Are any routes working?

Comment: your code works with  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false) ??

Comment: @BOSS Yes my code with html5mode diabled.

Comment: @AJFunk "not working" in  my sense means url gets updated but partial is not shown.I can see that my angular route is not getting matched. It always goes to otherwise in ng-route

Comment: what url are you using ?? without html 5 and with html 5

Comment: WIthout html5mode:
/store/1234/#!/department/produce /store/1234/#!/department/produce/category/fruits

With html5mode
/store/1234/department/produce /store/1234/#!/department/produce/category/fruits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My routing started working once I updated my base href as node server url:

`<head>
 <base href='/store/'+store.storeCode>
</head>`

Also I updated my angular routings urls prefixed with Store Code like:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/:storeid/department/:deptIndex', {
    //my routing code
});
```

Comment: Did it work for google bot? I got a site in html5mode without hashes in URLs but googlebot still treats them as duplicates :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the base url in your index.html?

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

You will also need to set html5mode to true and remove hashPrefix

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each route should have a template or a template URL , and your HTML should have ng-view to see the route content

Comment: Is using template or template URL mandatory? I am not using them anywhere in my code. My routing works absolutely fine if html5mode is disabled.

Comment: Your code will still work without template or templateURL, but you will the whole point of using routing. What does it mean 'content not updating' in your question description